# The context of definition of work

Tags: energy, work

It is unclear whether the work is defined considering opposite force on the same body or in ideal case where there is a single force acting on a body.If we consider ideal case where only a single force is present on the body, the displacement will not attain a specefic value. It will go on increasing and we cannot fix the value of displacement, I mean when do we say a force has worked on a body? Do we say this when a certain force has to' work' against another opposite force to cause displacement? I think the work is defined considering 2nd case since only then we can have a fix value of displacement because when one force is removed the other force will eventually stop the body.

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53708/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106570/

Answer (score 0):

I mean when do we say a force has worked on a body?

Whenever a force($F$) acts on a body and creates a displacement($S$), we say work has been done by that force on the body. Yes that applied force can work against another force as well, but the point to note that THERE IS A FORCE ON THE BODY. The basic equation is : $W$=$FScos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $F$ and $S$.

Sometimes force and displacement are both non-zero but still we get no work done because the $cos\theta$ term might be zero. Anyway, you can figure out such possibilities from looking at the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for the work done by an individual force, or the total (or net) work done on an object.   Consider a mass attached to a spring, the mass initially at rest.   I apply a constant force of 1 N, and the mass moves 1 m and then stops. The work done by my hand on the book is 1 J. The force and displacement are in the same direction, so the work done by my hand is greater than zero.  But there is another force on the mass, that due to the spring.  That force also does work on the mass.   The direction is opposite the force applied by my hand, and is opposite the direction of motion.  The work done by the spring is less than zero.

Both forces do work.  The total work done on the mass is zero in this case: the positive and negative values sum to zero.  I know this without doing the math because I specified that the mass started at rest and ended at rest.

A few more details:

- the work done *by the mass on the spring* is not zero.  The spring ends up with more potential energy than it started with.
- I specified that my hand applies a constant force. The force due to the spring depends on displacement. This implies that the speed of the mass will be changing during the push.

  However ...
- My setup is internally inconsistent.  I can't specify a constant force and then say that the mass was moving and then came to rest.  I must reduce my applied force in order for the mass to come to rest.  A detailed analysis would take that into account, but it doesn't change the point of my answer, which is to clarify what we mean when we talk about work.